# How to set up a wcf service that only serves to one client (or a fixed number of clients)?

Tags: wcf-security

I have a wcf service hosted in IIS. Currently this service is required to be accessed by only one internet facing application (Client A). Both client and server has proper production certificates installed. I have a feeling that I can use them identify each other as that's one of the purpose of certifcates but I am so confused with so many flair of configuration options available in WCF. What is the best and concise way of achieving it. A lot of solution seems to either rely on username/password way regardless of where the client appiication is or either just identify client by using

```
<message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
```

However I am using clientCerdentialType = "UserName" in order to use username/password scheme of authentication and authorisation.

I looked at the similar question at [How to configure a WCF service to only accept a single client identified by a x509 certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276594/how-to-configure-a-wcf-service-to-only-accept-a-single-client-identified-by-a-x5) but no luck.

Comment: Looks Like I should be using 
    <message clientCredentialType="Username" /> 
which by default requires client to be verified by a valid certificate.